# How to create a custom theme in SXA?

Tags: best-practices, sxa

SXA is coming with two predefined themes - `Basic` and `Wireframe`.

They are stored in `/sitecore/media library/Themes` media folder and cannot be modified in `Creative Exchange`.

What is the best way to create custom theme that I can apply to my site?

I am thinking about using standard Sitecore `Copying` -> `Copy To` item menu for `Wireframe` theme but would like to hear if there is a better option.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two ways of doing that:

- create your theme using **Create new Site dialogue**
- create your theme manually

**1. Create new Site dialogue**

Create New Site dialogue lets you create your own theme.

To do it you need to switch to **Theme** tab and check **Create new theme** checkbox

[image]

After that your site theme will be created somewhere here:

`/sitecore/media library/Project/Tenant/Site/My Site Theme`

**2. Create your theme manually**

If you want to do it manually you need to repeat script steps.

What scaffolding script does is:

- create new Theme item
- assign theme base templates
  [image]
- copy all content of **Basic** theme under your new Theme
- assign your new theme to allowed/compatible themes in your site settings
  You can configure them here:

[image]

Without that step, your new theme will not appear in any site options, for example here (device to theme mapping)

[image]

Comment: Any chance you will add a "New theme" dialog?

Comment: @michael-west I think it is a good idea

Comment: Another way is that you can use SXA CLI to create theme. That also help you to code your theme separately.