# How to use different themes folder for an SXA site?

Tags: sxa

I have two different sites. SiteA and SiteB (Cloned version of SiteA). I want SiteB to point to themes folder of SiteA instead of its own. I have updated the field 'Themes Folder' of SiteB site item but still SiteB is referring its own themes. Is there any configuration I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the reference in multiple places

ThemesFolder of Site home node
and Presentation - Designsand - Styling section, select the theme you want to use.

Comment: But the Presentation item has no such fields. Are you referring to Presentation -> Page Design -> Styling -> Theme field. I have updated there too.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below article for change the theme. I did the same and assigned a different theme instead of the default theme.

- https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/assign-a-theme.html **(Official Document)**
- [How to create a custom theme in SXA?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1994/how-to-create-a-custom-theme-in-sxa) **(StackExchange question)**
- https://tothecore.sk/2018/03/28/changing-theme-for-sitecore-experience-commerce-sxc-9/ **(Blog)**

Thanks.